# Custom Telerik DataViz chart tooltip color

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc, kendo-dataviz

I have a chart with many colors. The tooltip should appear as black or white depending on the background color of the chart's bar. The only option I can think of is handle this with the `series.name`. But nothing works.

This code does accurately put a white or a black piece of text onto the screen as a tooltip:

```
.Tooltip(tooltip =>
    tooltip.Visible(true).Template("# if ((series.name === 'foo') || (series.name === 'bah')) { return '<strong style=\"color: black\">bar</strong>'; } else { return '<strong style=\"color: white\">bar</strong>'; } #")
)
```

However, once I plug in `#= series.name # #= value #` instead of `bar` the function breaks down and it no longer works.

Next, I tried both SharedTemplate and Template as such (one at a time of course):

```
.Tooltip(tooltip =>
   tooltip.Visible(true).Template("mytemplate")
   tooltip.Visible(true).SharedTemplate("mytemplate")
)

<script id="mytemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
   # if ((series.name === 'foo') || (series.name === 'bah')) { #
      <strong style="color: black">bar</strong>
   # } else { #
      <strong style="color: white">bar</strong>
   # } #
</script>
```

This didn't do anything and instead displayed a tooltip of "mytemplate".

Is this possible to do? If not is there any kind of work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to set the tooltip color on the series itself:

```
 .Series(series => {
    series.Column(new double[] { 1, 2, 3}).Name("India").Tooltip(t=>t.Background("#fff"));
    series.Column(new double[] { 4, 5, 6 }).Name("Russian Federation").Tooltip(t => t.Background("#000"));
    series.Column(new double[] { 7, 8, 9}).Name("Germany").Tooltip(t => t.Background("#fff"));
})
```